# how to register users of different kinds using different tables in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, I want to register users using different tables for different users like students, teaching staff, non teaching staff, 3 tables.

How can i do it instead of using default auth_users table for registration

Comment: please dont set useless or irrelevant tags (fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, you should generally only have one User model. That way, functions that are common across user types (for example, logging in and logging out) can all be performed by referencing the same set of tables in the database.

If you want to register different user types, you have a few different options. You could either extend the default user model and create subclasses that have unique properties (see the Django documentation for more information on how to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model); or, you could create your own custom User model that has a switch that marks users as either Students, Teaching Staff, or Non-Teaching Staff (see the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). Alternately, you could also just add your users to Groups, and give them different permissions based on the Groups that they are in.

Either of these approaches could work, but at the end of the day all of your user models should sit under one overarching master class.

Answer (score 0):

In **Django** authentication, there is `Group` model available which have *many to many* relationship with `User` model. You can add `students`, `teaching staff` and `non teaching staff` to `Group` model for separating `users` by their type.

Answer (score 0):

cf Sam's answer for the proper solutions from a technical POV.  From a design POV, "student", "teaching staff" etc are not entities but different roles a user can have.

One curious things with living persons and real-life things in general is that they tend to evolve over time without any respect for our well-defined specifications and classifications - for example it's not uncommon for a student to also have teaching duties at some points, for a teacher to also be studying some other topic, or for a teacher to stop teaching and switch to more administrative tasks. If you design your model with distinct entities instead of one single entitie and distinct roles, it won't properly accomodate those kind of situations (and no, having one account as student and one as teacher is not a proper solution either).

That's why the default user model in Django is based on one single entity (the User model) and features allowing roles definitions (groups and permissions) in such a way that one user can have many roles, whether at the same time or in succession.